# copy a field from one data source to other in tableau

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence, tableau-api

I wanted to get rid off one  data source in Tableau, that's why instead of using 2 different data source for one dashboard, I wanted to copy all relevant fields from one data source to other. Is there any way in Tableau, by which I can copy-paste tos field from one to other data source?

In the attached screenshot, I wanted to copy the `advisor sales` field in data source `biadvisorSalesmonth24` to `bitransactionPartnerDay365`:

[image: In the attached screenshot, I wanted to copy the 'advisor sales' field in data source 'biadvisorSalesmonth24' to 'bitransactionPartnerDay365']

Comment: This question is very vague.  Please try to clarify your question and include any code that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make schema or structure changes to a table / datasource from within Tableau. If `advisor sales` is not in the `bitransactionPartnerDay365` data source, then you will have to keep both data sources in the workbook and join them together.

Now, if you are familiar with the datasets and know the necessary table layout, you could write a custom SQL command and use that SQL command to retrieve the desired data as a single data source.